# Nutch Indexing to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hdfs, nutch

I'm struggling with indexing Nutch crawled data into ElasticSearch. I ran Nutch in deploy mode with 2 HDFS nodes, and it worked fine.

However, after adding another HDFS node (a total of 3 HDFS nodes), Nutch Indexing Plugin doesn't work well.

- Nutch Segment1 that is supposed to result in 45 documents indexed in
  ElasticSearch, is well-indexed.
- Nutch Segment2 is supposed to result in about 1600 documents indexed
  in ElasticSearch, which is good too.
- But, Nutch Segment3, which is supposed to result in about 9000
  documents indexed in elasticsearch, isn't indexed.

[image]

All of the nutch segments were able to be indexed with 2 HDFS.

I don't know what the cause of this situation is. nutch indexing command tells me map/reduce job is ok and documents are indexed.

(I think one of the alleged causes is ElasticSearch's circuit breaker. ES circuit breaker is triggered, and then the indexing request is cut. But How to ensure the circuit breaker has been triggered? There is no log for that.)

Comment: Please share the command used for indexing

Comment: I think it was bin/crawl -i -s <SEED_URL_PATH> <DATA_PATH> <#itertation>
Now I've figured out what was problem(alleged). the problem was one of my hadoop data node doesn't know the other hadoop datanode's ip address.
But i still don't know why there was no error log during map/reduce.